# Функция сохранения файла и передача параметров в нее

Tags: c++, winapi

Я пробую написать обычную программу на `С++` с `WinApi` которая будет сохранять текст из `editbox` в текстовый файл.
Дабы сократить код в функции `DlgProc`, хочу вынести функцию сохранения файла в отдельную функцию, что бы кнопка вызывала просто имя функции. Интересует следующее, какие параметры функции ей передавать?
Код самой программы я приложил.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "resource.h"

using namespace std;

#define ESC_OF "Отказ от выбора или ошибка выполнения функции "


HWND hEdit2;


CHAR text[] = { 0 };

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR lpCmdLine,
int nCmdShow)
{
    DialogBoxParam(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, (DlgProc), 0);
    return 0;
}

BOOL CALLBACK DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    BOOL success;
    static OPENFILENAME ofn;
    static char szFile[MAX_PATH];


    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_INITDIALOG: { // Добавление компонентов на форму


                      // Инициализация структуры ofn

    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwnd;
    ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
    ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
    ofn.lpstrFilter = "Text Files (*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files (*.*)\0*.*\0";
    ofn.lpstrDefExt = "txt";


    //Иконка
    HICON hIcon1 = LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
    SendMessage(hwnd, WM_SETICON, 1, (LPARAM)hIcon1);
    //Текстовые поля
    hEdit2 = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT2);
    SetWindowText(hEdit2, text);
    SetFocus(hEdit2);
    break;
    return TRUE;
} 
case WM_COMMAND:// Обработка кнопок и нажатий
    switch (LOWORD(wParam)) 
    {
    case IDC_SAVE:
        strcpy_s(szFile, "");
        success = GetSaveFileName(&ofn);

        if (success) {
            MessageBox(hwnd, ofn.lpstrFile,
                "Файл сохранен под именем:", MB_OK);
            HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile,
                GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,
                CREATE_ALWAYS,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                NULL);
            const int size = 2048;
            TCHAR buff[size] = { 0 };
            hEdit2 = GetDlgItem(hwnd, IDC_EDIT2);
            DWORD off = 0;

            do {
                GetWindowText(hEdit2, buff, size);
                WriteFile(hFile, buff, size, &off, NULL);
            } while (off < 0);

            CloseHandle(hFile);
        }
        else {
            MessageBox(hwnd, ESC_OF"GetSaveFileName",
                "Отказ от выбора или ошибка", MB_ICONWARNING);
        }

        break;

    case IDOK:
        MessageBox(hwnd, "Была нажата кнопка ОК", "Info",
            MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        break;

    case IDCANCEL:
        EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
        return FALSE;
    }

    break;

case WM_CLOSE:
    EndDialog(hwnd, 0);
    return FALSE;
}

return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Слишком много переменных объявляется и инициализируется в данной ф-ии. И не меньшее их количество используется в кейсе IDC_SAVE. Так что при текущей реализации - имхо, создавать отдельную ф-ию - не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если бы файл создавался и писался одним куском данных сразу, то можно было просто создать функцию в которую можно передать например имя файла плюс данные для записи, тогда бы это была функция создания файла с заданным именем и данными. Также можно было бы если хочется диалог получения имени файла тоже вызывать из этой функции, тогда нужно было бы в функцию передать уже не имя файла, а например сообщение для заголовка диалога, тогда это была бы функция для создания произвольного выбранного пользователем файла с заданными данными. Но т.к. вижу что файл в примере пишется по кускам это означает что функцией одной не обойтись (конечно можно в Си стиле хранить контекст в глобальной переменной), т.к. нужен контекст для записи одного файла, тогда можно было бы создать класс, который бы при создании в конструкторе получал либо имя файла либо если хотим диалог встроить в класс тогда вместо имени файла было бы заголовок диалога, также в деструкторе открывался бы хэндл класса через CreateFile, плюс у класса был бы дополнительный метод типа `void write(uint8_t const * data, u32 size)` для записи очередного куска, а хэндл на файл хранился бы членом класса, в деструкторе нужно закрывать хэндл файла через CloseHandle.

```
class FileWriter {
public:
    FileWriter(std::string const & dialog_message) {
        ...
        ofn.lpstrTitle = dialog_message.c_str();
        GetSaveFileName(&ofn);
        hFile_ = CreateFile(ofn.lpstrFile ...);
    }

    ~FileWriter() { CloseHandle(hFile); }

    void Write(uint8_t const * data, uint32_t size) {
        WriteFile(hFile_, data, size, 0, 0);
    }
private:
    HANDLE hFile_;
};
```